# Repeating Strings in Java to reach a certain length

Tags: java, string, loops, encryption, iteration

I am coding a program to encrypt phrases using a keyword. Firstly, the user will be asked to enter a keyword of their choice. They will then be asked to enter a phrase they would like to be encrypted. The issue I have is as follows:

If the user's keyword is: hello
And their phrase for encryption is: goodbye

The keyword has to be iterated so that the full word for encryption, 'goodbye' can be encrypted. For example:

```
hellohe
goodbye
```

How do I iterate the String so that only 'h' and 'e' are iterated again?

Comment: you have to make 'goodbye'.length iterations. i - index of current iteration. Than index of symbol in keyword is i%'hello'.length. % - return the remainder of devision

Comment: @Z. Grande Do you have any other queries, if you do, leave it in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String keyword = "hello";
String phrase = "goodbye";
for (int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++) {
    char p = phrase.charAt(i);
    char k = keyword.charAt(i % keyword.length());
    System.out.println(p + " + " + k + " = " + (char)((p-'a' + k-'a')%26+'a'));
}
```

*Output*

```
g + h = n
o + e = s
o + l = z
d + l = o
b + o = p
y + h = f
e + e = i
```

Comment: I have used your method but am trying to use the positions in the alphabet so that 'a' is position 1 instead of 0. I simply added '+1' after '%26' however, using this method results in 'z' being encrypted as '{'. How can I encrypt it as 'a'?

Comment: Not sure I follow. `p-'a'` is 0-25, so `+1` is 1-26. Same for `k`. `%26` is also 0-25, and `+1` is 1-26. If you have an value of `x` being 1-26 and want `a`-`z`, then `x-1+'a'` will do it.

Answer (score 2):

The `StringUtils` class from the third party [Apache Commons Lang](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.4) has the [rightPad](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#rightPad(java.lang.String,%20int,%20java.lang.String)) method that exactly fit your needs

You can use it like

```
String myword = StringUtils.rightPad("hello", "goodbye".length(), "hello");
```

Comment: You probably could use `""` as first `String` as well.

Comment: You might want to mention that it's from a third party jar file, and where to get it.

Comment: @Andreas Yep, that could be useful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you are ciphering each letter for "goodbye", check against the length of your encryption key "hello".

Just for illustration, if your encrypted text is just to add `msg` with `key`:

```
for(int x=0; x<msg.length(); x++)
    encryptedChar = msg.charAt(x) + key.charAt(x % key.length());
```